# Change Starting point of data in Column in delphi

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am using Developer Express components - TdxDBgrid as Grid and TdxMemData as dataset.

There are around 10 columns displayed in grid.

For the second column, I am trying to change starting point where column value displayed. I am trying to do it using ACanvas.TextRect. But the changes are not getting affected. Anybody having idea how to change starting position of data in Column for any grid.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if what you're asking is how to shift the x-position where the text starts, but if it is, try something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.dxDBGrid1Column2CustomDrawCell(Sender: TObject;
  ACanvas: TCanvas; ARect: TRect; ANode: TdxTreeListNode;
  AColumn: TdxTreeListColumn; ASelected, AFocused, ANewItemRow: Boolean;
  var AText: String; var AColor: TColor; AFont: TFont;
  var AAlignment: TAlignment; var ADone: Boolean);
var
  XOffset : Integer;
begin
  XOffset := 20;
  ACanvas.FillRect(ARect);
  ACanvas.TextOut(ARect.Left + XOffset, ARect.Top, AText);
  ADone := True;
end;
```

Obviously that doesn't deal with details like how to draw selected and focused columns, etc, but you should get the idea and you can look at the DevEx source for those.

Comment: yes I am doing same in  CustomDraw Procedure, but its not getting effected. Thanks for Answer. Any idea in any other Grid how we can do that?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact code you're using.

Comment: ohh.. what a fullish mistake I was doing.. I am not making ADone:= true.

Comment: Got answer. thanks a lot Martyn. Really appriciate your help.